# Going from an explicit height using row-span, to a max-height based on content

Tags: html, tailwind-css, css-grid

Just wondering if it's possible to go from setting an element's height using `row-start-x` and `row-span-x`, and then at a different break point revert to the size being determined by the content?

In the attached image you can see that the content element grows in height because at smaller sizes I'm setting `sm:row-end-8` and `sm:row-span-3`, but I'd rather it didn't at certain sizes.

Thanks!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/OJdrOzx?editors=1010

```js
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="mx-auto py-12 bg-blue-600 sm:bg-green-500  md:bg-purple-500 w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="card border border-red-500 relative  grid sm:grid-cols-8 lg:grid-cols-1 sm:grid-rows-6  gap-y-4 sm:gap-y-0 lg:gap-y-6 w-full">
    <img class="card__image border border-blue-500 object-fill sm:col-start-2 sm:col-span-7 sm:row-start-1 sm:row-span-5 rounded-lg shadow" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/Snowboard_pow.jpg/1280px-Snowboard_pow.jpg" />

    <div class="card__content bg-slate-500 border border-yellow-500 sm:row-end-7 sm:row-span-3 md:row-end-7  flex flex-col pb-7 pt-5 lg:px-4 xl:px-8 space-y-2.5 shadow rounded-lg bg-slate-50 grow sm:col-start-1  sm:col-span-6">
      <div class=" flex items-center pl-4 pr-6 lg:pl-2 sm:py-1 gap-x-4 leading-7 text-gray-600 text-lg  font-semibold  ">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-full ">{icon}</div>
        <div class="">
          {title}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" pl-7 lg:pl-3 pr-5 text-base md:text-lg md:leading-7 text-gray-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam culpa earum perspiciatis tempore quisquam ea vitae, suscipit nostrum hic. Quod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit voluptatibus obcaecati laudantium illo
        magnam tempora quod sequi, porro eius repellendus.</div>
      <a class="flex grow justify-end items-end space-x-1  pl-7 lg:pl-3 pr-7 font-medium  text-primary">
        <div class="flex gap-2">
          <div>{linkText}</div>
          <ArrowTopRight class="text-primary w-3 h-3" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the "certain sizes" that you don't what the content element to grow in height, but you can apply `align-self: start` to the element to have it be as high as its content:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="mx-auto py-12 bg-blue-600 sm:bg-green-500  md:bg-purple-500 w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="card border border-red-500 relative  grid sm:grid-cols-8 lg:grid-cols-1 sm:grid-rows-6  gap-y-4 sm:gap-y-0 lg:gap-y-6 w-full">
    <img class="card__image border border-blue-500 object-fill sm:col-start-2 sm:col-span-7 sm:row-start-1 sm:row-span-5 rounded-lg shadow" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/Snowboard_pow.jpg/1280px-Snowboard_pow.jpg" />

    <div class="card__content bg-slate-500 border border-yellow-500 sm:row-end-7 sm:row-span-3 md:row-end-7  flex flex-col pb-7 pt-5 lg:px-4 xl:px-8 space-y-2.5 shadow rounded-lg bg-slate-50 grow sm:col-start-1  sm:col-span-6 sm:self-start">
      <div class=" flex items-center pl-4 pr-6 lg:pl-2 sm:py-1 gap-x-4 leading-7 text-gray-600 text-lg  font-semibold  ">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-full ">{icon}</div>
        <div class="">
          {title}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" pl-7 lg:pl-3 pr-5 text-base md:text-lg md:leading-7 text-gray-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam culpa earum perspiciatis tempore quisquam ea vitae, suscipit nostrum hic. Quod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit voluptatibus obcaecati laudantium illo
        magnam tempora quod sequi, porro eius repellendus.</div>
      <a class="flex grow justify-end items-end space-x-1  pl-7 lg:pl-3 pr-7 font-medium  text-primary">
        <div class="flex gap-2">
          <div>{linkText}</div>
          <ArrowTopRight class="text-primary w-3 h-3" />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```